How to convert Sentinel-2 RGB bands to [0, 255]
I have already downloaded the Sentinel-2 RGB bands using earthengine-api with python. The resultant numpy matrix has a shape (n, m, 3), representing the RGB bands directly downloaded from Sentinel-2.
The values are between 300 and 2000 more or less, and I want to know where this values come from, and how to convert them to [0, 255] or [0, 1].
Currently I am using a percent clip and the results are quite good, but I want a perfect conversion for the data. I leave the code I am using below just in case someone might find it helpful.
def sentinel2_to_rgb(image):
    low_percent = 0.5
    high_percent = 99.5

    image_clip = np.zeros_like(image)
    for band in range(image.shape[2]):
        low_percent_val = np.percentile(image[:, :, band], low_percent)
        high_percent_val = np.percentile(image[:, :, band], high_percent)
        image_clip[:, :, band] = ((image[:, :, band] - low_percent_val) /
                                  (high_percent_val - low_percent_val))
        image_clip[:, :, band] = np.clip(image_clip[:, :, band], 0, 1)

    return image_clip


"Perfect conversion" is not a reasonable goal when reducing multi-band multi-byte data into a single byte -- It's all about compromises.

By ‘perfect conversion’ I mean a method by which I get colours that represent the real image regardless of the context of the image, since, as it is now, the values removed by the percentiles depend on each image, and the conversion is not regular.

Which product did you download, surface or TOA reflectance? Are you aware of the harmonized L2A data and that the 12 UINT16 bit spectral bands representing surface reflectance are scaled by 10000? Please know your data. There is some information in the GEE catalogue (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/sentinel-2/) but, please track down the Sentinal-2 handbook.

Find a low_percent_val and high_percent_val that you like, then hard code them so the same values are used for every image

Hello and thank you @JeffreyEvans. I was using an old method to get TOA reflectance images, but thanks to the page you sent me, I realised that what I was really looking for was surface reflectance. Also, browsing through the guide you indicated, I found the way to make the conversion 'perfect', leave the code below.
def sentinel2_l2a_to_rgb(image):
    min_val = 0.0
    max_val = 0.3
    rgb_image = (image / 10000 - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)
    rgb_image[rgb_image < 0] = 0
    rgb_image[rgb_image > 1] = 1
    return rgb_image

I hope someone will find it useful.
